# How to require a requirejs module using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, sapui5

Lets say i have this ResourceBundleContext.js file (requirejs module):

```
sap.ui.define([
   "sap/ui/model/resource/ResourceModel"
], function (ResourceModel)
{
    'use strict';
    var resourceBundleContext = function ()
    {
        var i18nModel = new ResourceModel({
            bundleName: "sap/rules/ui/src/sap/rules/ui/lib/parser/i18n.messages_descriptions"
        });
        return {
            getString: function (messageKey, paramsArray)
            {
                var oBundle = i18nModel.getResourceBundle();
                var sMsg = oBundle.getText(messageKey, paramsArray);
                jQuery.sap.log.debug("code: " + messageKey + ", params: " + paramsArray + "\nMessage: " + sMsg);
                return sMsg;
            }
        };
    };
    return new resourceBundleContext;
});
```

in the path:

```
sap.hrf.ui.uilib.js.parser.infrastructure.locale.lib.resourceBundleContext
```

And i want to require this above module using jquery, this will bot be good:

```
jQuery.sap.require("sap.hrf.ui.uilib.js.parser.infrastructure.locale.lib.resourceBundleContext");
```

How i can require a requirejs module using jQuery?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean with "will not be good"? Do you get an error message in the console? Does the loading fail? Are you not able to access the object after the require?

Comment: @schnoedel hi, i mean that it will not require the fail, it calls the file but not require him, after i do : var ResourceBundleContext = sap.hrf.ui.uilib.js.parser.infrastructure.locale.lib.resourceBundleContext; ResourceBundleContext  will be undifined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because you are mixing the 'old' synchronous requirejs and the new asynchronous AMD modules. You have two possible solutions:

1. In your module definition you have to give [sap.ui.define()](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.html#.define) `true` as last parameter to export the module into the global namespace so that you can access it after a `jquery.sap.require()`.

```js
sap.ui.define([
   "sap/ui/model/resource/ResourceModel"
], function (ResourceModel)
{
    'use strict';
    var resourceBundleContext = function ()
    {
        var i18nModel = new ResourceModel({
            bundleName: "sap/rules/ui/src/sap/rules/ui/lib/parser/i18n.messages_descriptions"
        });
        return {
            getString: function (messageKey, paramsArray)
            {
                var oBundle = i18nModel.getResourceBundle();
                var sMsg = oBundle.getText(messageKey, paramsArray);
                jQuery.sap.log.debug("code: " + messageKey + ", params: " + paramsArray + "\nMessage: " + sMsg);
                return sMsg;
            }
        };
    };
    return new resourceBundleContext;
}, true /* export to global namespace */); //<-- there's the true
```

2. You have to use [sap.ui.require()](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.html#.require) to load your AMD module the AMD way:

```js
sap.ui.require("sap/hrf/ui/uilib/js/parser/infrastructure/locale/lib/resourceBundleContext",
               function(resourceBundleContext){
                 // called asynchronously when the module has loaded.
                 // resourceBundleContext is your module
               });
```

Comment: can you please write where in the end i need to write true?

Comment: Thanks a lot!, there is a damage in the performance when using the modules as global?

Comment: well, `jquery.sap.require` issues a synchronous ajax request to load the module file the first time. That might block your ui thread for a while. Thats one reason why ui5 has migrated to the asynchronous AMD pattern.

Answer (score 2):

In the module that utilizes the `resourceBundleContext`, you could also use a similar AMD pattern as you did in the definition of `resourceBundleContext`, e.g.:

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/hrf/ui/uilib/js/parser/infrastructure/locale/lib/resourceBundleContext"
], function (ResourceBundleContext)
{
    'use strict';

    var AwesomeApp = function ()
    {
        var resourceBundleContext = new ResourceBundleContext();
        alert(resourceBundleContext.getString("AwesomeKey", ["AwesomeParms"]));
    };

    return AwesomeApp;

});
```

Building all your modules in the AMD style throughout your UI5 app provides a level of consistency and increases performance of loading the required modules.

Please also note that SAP's didn't leverage require.js in its implementation of `define` and is also not fully compatible with require.js or other AMD loaders. You can read more on SAP's implementation as well as the differences with require.js on https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.html#.define